# What is "C:\$Extend\$Reparse:$R:$INDEX_ALLOCATION" in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, ntfs, process, file-permissions

ProcMon.exe tells me that many different processes including ones owned by standard users, admins, and the SYSTEM user are receiving "ACCESS DENIED" error results when trying to read "C:/$Extend/$Reparse:$R:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".

Google returns nothing useful from MSDN, but i assume these are NTFS or Windows Search folders.  What processes need to be able to r C:\$Extend? w? x?

Set the ProcMon.exe filter to include contains "C:\" for path and include contains "ACCESS DENIED", but exclude "SUCCESS" for results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This folder is part of the disks [NTFS metadata](http://ntfs.com/ntfs-system-files.htm).

You should never see NTFS meta-structures, so thats one mystery, but either way [$EXTEND](https://flatcap.org/linux-ntfs/ntfs/files/extend.html) is NOT user readable, and you should never ever touch it.

[Reparse Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point) are structures that allow the disk to be extended, by including non-contigious data, like volume mount points, hard links, etc.

Comment: It should be added that `$INDEX_ALLOCATION` is a MFT attribute that contains a list of children of said directory.